# Notion of orthogonality in clustering

Tags: clustering, data-mining

I'm reading in a paper "*the goal is to cluster data in a way that is meaningful and at the same time as orthogonal as possible to the given classification*"

Could someone have any idea how the notion of orthogonality is used in this case?

Comment: without reading the paper i dont know but my guess is independence.

Comment: actually, i'm thinking the same. if it helps, the paper is in the context of Information Bottleneck method.

Comment: Can you add a proper citation, or better an on-line version of the paper?

Comment: Conditional Information Bottleneck Clustering http://www.cs.brown.edu/~th/papers/GonHof2003_CondIB.pdf

Comment: @RyanB I don't think this really qualifies as an answer so I'll convert it to a comment. Feel free to post a revised and argumentative response.

Comment: Since "orthogonal" is used in the same sentence with "meaningful," which is a thoroughgoingly subjective term, we really ought to understand both words in a *colloquial* sense rather than a technical one.  Some people apply "orthogonal" in such circumstances to mean, in some loose sense, "independent of" or "separate from."  Since no citation was offered and the link has since rotted, that leaves this question unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

If it's talking about "variable clustering" then it makes sense.  When clustering variables, you want to put them in groups such that variables in each group are as correlated to each other as possible, and as uncorrelated to variables in other groups as possible.  In the best case the groups are orthogonal.

If clustering here refers to clustering observations, I have no idea what orthogonality is referring to.